# For scanning images, what are the functional differences between Preview and Image Capture?

Tags: preview, scanning, image-capture

I know that for Preview I can annotate an image or scan. And I know that for Image Capture I can have it capture images from a device like a camera. But, specific to just the scanning aspect, are there are the same underneath?

In other words are they the same plumbing but with different porcelain (to use Torvald's analogy of Linux distros) or are they fundamentally different?

Answer (score 1):

Both apps use the same frameworks to provide the import of an image from a scanner (or Phone, etc).

Image Capture is focused on importing images, in batches, from cameras, as well as scanning.

Preview is an image viewer with some small editing capabilities, that can also import one image at a time from another device.